# javascript array to html <li>

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist

I got an array from json and I need to put each item in a `<li>` on my html

something like this :

```
names : {john, paul, ringo,george}
into <li>john</li>..
```

my code:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

script:

```
function onLocationsReceived(data) {
  console.log("recievd");

  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Sensors.length; i++) {
    var sensorNames = data[0].Sensors[i].Name;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sensorNames;
    console.log(sensorNames);
  }
}
```

on the concole.log it prints just fine..

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<li>' + sensorNames '</li>
```

something like that???

Comment: As per your code you are overwriting the text in your inner html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing each value of an array on a separate line Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392109/printing-each-value-of-an-array-on-a-separate-line-javascript)

Comment: I suggest to create temporary string variable for `<li>` elements, and then after building it - to write it as .innerHTML. Instead of doing `+=`. It's better for performance and easily to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like below

```
function onLocationsReceived(data){
var html="";
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Sensors.length; i++) {
   var sensorNames = data[0].Sensors[i].Name;
    html+="<li>"+sensorNames+"</li>";
    console.log(sensorNames);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=html;
}
```

Comment: Can someone please edit my answer not able to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use syntax below

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML ='<li>' + sensorNames + '</li>'
```

Comment: See my previous comment about the `+=` and put the: _you can use  below syntax_ inside a comment line - to make it more copy pastable

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the iterative sensorNames into a var with the li and then replace the innerHTML:

```
var content = "",
    sensorNames;

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].Sensors.length; i++) {
    sensorNames = data[0].Sensors[i].Name;
    content += "<li>" + sensorNames + "</li>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = content;
```