# Looped Array does not print in single lines

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"]
for (var i = 0; i<colours.length; i++){
  document.write(" " + colours [i]);
}
```

I have to create a web page that has a series of colours stored in a array to loop through each element. The problem is, the result is all the colours in one single line. How do I make it so it outputs in a new line everytime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing each value of an array on a separate line Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392109/printing-each-value-of-an-array-on-a-separate-line-javascript)

Comment: @CalvinNunes same solution, but different premise. I'm not sure it applies, but let the community decide :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `<br>` tag in the `document.write`. `<br>` creates a line break which will print the next element in the new line

```js
var colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"]
for (var i = 0; i<colours.length; i++){
    document.write(" " + colours [i] + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following - add a break tag [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) and to further simplify, you can also use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to avoid loop.

```js
var colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"]
document.write(colours.join("<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `<br>` element to create a new line in your HTML.

You can also create a single string and write it once to your document. For that, map your color array to the colors plus the `<br>` using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then join this array using [`Array.join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"];

document.write(colours.map(c => `${c}<br>`).join(''));
```

Or more simply, join the color array with the `<br>` string:

```js
const colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"];

document.write(colours.join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the break line tag **< br >**

```js
var colours = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Black","Orange"]
for (var i = 0; i<colours.length; i++){
  document.write("<span style='background-color:"+colours[i]+"'>" + colours [i] +"</span><br>");
}
```